# How do I position page numbers on the top right of my page while using a 0.5 in margin on each side?

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}


%Border
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

I have tried using fancyhdr; however, the page number goes to the top most right corner and is barely visible. I understand that the margin is small but I would still like it to be visible by making it lower down. How can I do this please? I added an image of the output that I got when I used fancy hdr.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\raisebox{<negative distance>}{<text>}`

[image: a]

Added `showframe` to show margins.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}

%Border
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-0.8\headsep}{\thepage}} % lowering the right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```